# How can I take and share a screenshot without using the external storage?

Tags: android, permissions, screenshot

I would like to programatically take a screenshot and share it using a *ShareActionProvider* without asking for the "*android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE*" permission.
I'm trying to do this because I want to avoid asking for permissions if it's not absolutely necessary and to be able to deal with devices without external storage.

I managed to successfully send the screenshot to some apps, but there is at least one (Gmail) that won't attach my screenshot.
Here's my code:

```
...
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    ...
    MenuItem shareMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
    ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareMenuItem);
    shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
    shareActionProvider.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(new ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider source, Intent intent)
        {
            saveScreenshot();
            // The return result is ignored. Return false for consistency.
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private Intent createShareIntent() {
    // Get the path of the screenshot inside the directory holding application files.
    File screenshotFile = new File(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), SCREENSHOT_NAME);

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(screenshotFile));
    return shareIntent;
}

private void saveScreenshot() {
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    // Save on Internal Storage to avoid asking for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        // Open a file associated with this Context's application package for writing.
        // Make file readable by other apps otherwise it can't be shared.
        outputStream = getActivity().getApplicationContext()
                .openFileOutput(SCREENSHOT_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, COMPRESS_QUALITY, outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Can't save screenshot!", e);
    } finally {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            try {
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Can't close the output stream!", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```

This code works if I want to share with Twitter, Hangouts, Keep, Evernote, Inbox from Google and other apps I tested, but it doesn't work with Gmail.
For example on a Nexus 6, Gmail gives me a Toast message saying "*Permission denied*" and on a Nexus 4 it just doesn't attach the screenshot without any error message.
There is nothing relevant in the logs.
Using something like

```
screenshotFile.setReadable(true, false);
```

or

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 " + screenshotFile.getAbsolutePath());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Can't give permissions to screenshot file!", e);
}
```

does not make a difference.

If I save my screenshot on the external storage using *Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()* and ask for the "*android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE*" permission all apps I tested work fine.

How can I do this without using the external storage and have all apps (including Gmail) working?
Is it possible that this is a problem with the Gmail app?
Or would you advise me to just ask for the permission to write on the external storage and accept the fact that some of my users might complain and some devices don't have a SD card?

Thanks!

Comment: `deal with devices without external storage.`. All devices nowadays have external storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I do this without using the external storage and have all apps (including Gmail) working?

You can [try `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html), possibly in conjunction with [my `LegacyCompatCursorWrapper`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider#usage-legacycompatcursorwrapper).

> Is it possible that this is a problem with the Gmail app?

I would consider it to be a feature, not a bug. `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` has been deprecated for some time, with good reason. As it stands, your code is making your screenshot available to all apps, which is poor from a security standpoint. Proper use of a `ContentProvider` can limit access to one app (not all), for one request (this particular `ACTION_SEND` operation), for a limited amount of time. Perhaps the Gmail developers are just trying to give others a nudge in the right direction.

> some devices don't have a SD card?

[External storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on the *vast* majority of Android devices, including pretty much all of them that shipped with Android 3.0 or higher. If you are aware of a device model that shipped with something newer, for which external storage is a removable card, please let me know.

Comment: I used the FileProvider as @CommonsWare sugested and all apps, including Gmail, are now able to get the screenshot from the directory holding my app's files. I got rid of MODE_WORLD_READABLE.
I followed the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html) with only two exceptions:
- I don't use the path attribute in the filepaths.xml because the openFileOutput() method does not allow path separators.
- I grant permissions for all apps that can handle my intent and I revoke the permissions later using revokeUriPermission().

Answer (score 4):

This is what you would have to do to implement what you want using fileprovider. I've done it in my app.

Create a file as **res/xml/paths.xml** and add this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths >
    <cache-path name="shared_images" path="images/"/>
</paths>
```

Then declare the fileprovider in your **AndroidManifest.xml** android replace **android:authorities attribute** with your package name

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.harkunwar.testapp.fileprovider"
        <!--put your package name here-->
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/paths" />
            <!--put your xml file name here-->
</provider>
```

Then use this method to share your **Bitmap**

```
void share(Bitmap bitmap) {
    String fileName = "share.png";
    File dir = new File(getCacheDir(), "images");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, fileName);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName()+".fileprovider", file);

     Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
     intent.setType("image/*");
     intent.setDataAndType(uri, getContentResolver().getType(uri));
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Here's the shared image");
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

      try {
         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"));
      } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "No App Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
}
```

Then I use this simple code to share screenshot using the previous function.

```
View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
Bitmap screenshot = getScreenShot(rootView);
share(screenshot);
```